# In Variational Auto Encoders (VAEs), why is the variance predicted by the encoder lower for noise images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, variational-bayes

I am training a VAE on some images, and I want to have some sort of certainty quantifier. Given an input image, the encoder predicts mean and variance vectors, so naturally I thought that the variance vector will suit the task.

However, I noticed that even with MNIST digit data, once the network is trained to reconstruct the digits very well, the encoder gives a larger variance (vector norm) for actual digit images than for a complete noise image. Why is that? Why is the predicted variance higher for 'clean' data than it is for a random pixel image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A VAE models a distribution as

$$\log P(x) = \log \int P(x|z)P(z) dz \geq E_{z \sim q}[\log P(x|z)] - \text{KL}(q(z)||p(z))$$

As you can see, there is no direct relationship between the variance of $q$ and the probability the model assigns to a given datapoint $x$.

In fact decreasing the variance on $q$ could increase the KL term, resulting in lower log likelihood. Anyway I suggest using the ELBO or a monte carlo estimate of the integral to determine how much probability the model assigns to a particular image.